# Only copy visible range in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running into an issue where I'm unable to copy only visible cells to a new sheet. I'm able to get the lastrow, but I get #N/A on every cell except the first for each column. I want to just copy the visible cells. I'd also like to only put information on visible rows too, if possible?

Please see my code below:

```
Sub Importe()
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Row

Worksheets.Add

With ActiveSheet
  Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value2 = _
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
  Range("B1:B" & lastRow).Value2 = _
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: If you use `With ActiveSheet` then it is completely useless until you start something with a `.` like `.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value2 =` otherwise the `With` statement won't take effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `.Value2 = .Value` doesn't work on special cells of type visible, because …

… e.g. if `lastRow = 50` and there are `hiddenRows = 10` then …

- your source `Range("H1:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`
  has `lastRow - hiddenRows = 40` rows
- but your destination `Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Value2`
  has `lastRow = 50` rows.

On the first you subtract the visible rows, so they are different in size. Therefore `.Value2 = .Value` doesn't work, because you cannot fill 50 rows with only 40 source rows.

But what you can do is `Copy` and `SpecialPaste`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Importe()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Row

    Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveSheet
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Nevertheless I recommend to avoid `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveWorkbook` if this is possible and reference a workbook eg by `ThisWorkbook`. My suggestion:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Importe()
    Dim SourceWs As Worksheet
    Set SourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim DestinationWs As Worksheet
    Set DestinationWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = SourceWs.Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Row

    SourceWs.Range("H1:H" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DestinationWs.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    SourceWs.Range("E1:E" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    DestinationWs.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: lots of `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` here... ;-)

Comment: @DisplayName correct even I have lazy moments, but I added a better practice version. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

To define whether a cell is visible or not, both its column and row should be visible. This means, that the `.Hidden` property of the column and the row should be set to `False`.

Here is some sample code of how to copy only the visible ranges between two worksheets.

Imagine that you have an input like this in Worksheets(1):

[image]

Then you manually hide column `B` and you want to get in `Worksheets(2)` every cell from the `Range(A1:C4)`, without the ones in column `B`. Like this:

[image]

To do this, you should check each cell in the range, whether its column or row is visible or not.
A possible solution is this one:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell  As Range
    For Each myCell In Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C4")
        If (Not Rows(myCell.Row).Hidden) And (Not Columns(myCell.Column).Hidden) Then
            Dim newCell As Range
            Set newCell = Worksheets(2).Cells(myCell.Row, myCell.Column)
            newCell.Value2 = myCell.Value2
        End If
    Next myCell    
End Sub
```

---

Just a general advise - whenever you use something like this `Range("A1").Value2 = Range("A1").Value2` make sure that both are the same and not the left is `Value2` and the right is `.Value`. It probably will not bring what you are expecting.

Comment: Why use `Value2` at all? You might lose formatting in these kinds of examples

Comment: @CallumDA - the OP is using it, thus I assume he has some reason to do so.

Comment: They also used `Value` so perhaps they aren't sure which one to use :)

Comment: @CallumDA - yup, the usage of `.Value2 = .Value` is most probably a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform a direct value transfer without cycling though the areas of the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) collection.

Sometimes it is easier to copy everything and get rid of what you don't want.

```
Sub Importe()
    Dim lr As Long

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy after:=Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "xyz"
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Value2
        For lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(lr, "A").EntireRow.Hidden Then
                .Cells(lr, "A").EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next lr
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(lr, 1) = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(lr, 1).Offset(0, 7).Value2
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 1).Resize(lr, 1) = .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Resize(lr, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value2
        .Columns("C:XFD").EntireColumn.Delete
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just to throw in an alternative version:

```
Sub Importe()
    Dim sht1Rng As Range, sht1VisibleRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set sht1Rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Set sht1VisibleRng = sht1Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    With Worksheets.Add
        .Range("A1").Resize(sht1Rng.Rows.Count).Value2 = sht1Rng.Offset(, 7).Value2
        .Range("B1").Resize(sht1Rng.Rows.Count).Value2 = sht1Rng.Offset(, 4).Value2
        .UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        .Range(sht1VisibleRng.Address(False, False)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

which may have the drawback of `Address()` maximum "capacity "