# Excel VBA button. Copy rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2 / Condition: column value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using code below to copy rows from Sheet1 to Sheet2.
I have 3 questions about.

1. Why this function always copy row A2? Even if value is "0".
2. How to copy just value, no formatting?
3. Is it possible to skip column B when copy? "C" from Sheet1 will be "B" in Sheet2, etc.

> ```
> Sub COPY_SA()
> Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
> Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
> Dim lastrow As Long
> 'change Sheets to suit
> Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
> Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")
>
> With ws1
>     'assumung that your data stored in column A:D, Sheet1
>     lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
>     Set rng = .Range("A2:D" & lastrow)
>     'clear all filters
>     .AutoFilterMode = False
>     With rng
>         'apply filter
>         .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0"
>         On Error Resume Next
>         'get only visible rows
>         Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
>         On Error GoTo 0
>     End With
>     'copy range
>     If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.CopyDestination:=ws2.Range("A2")
>     'clear all filters
>     .AutoFilterMode = False
> End With
> Application.CutCopyMode = False End Sub
> ```

I manage to modify like below. Still have issue with range in Worksheet "ws1". Cannot set filter in second row and copy range from row 3. That is why added: "ws2.Rows(3).Delete". Code always copy row 1.
Row 1 got some comments.
Row 2 got column names.

> ```
> Sub COPY_SA()
> Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
> Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
> Dim lastrow As Long
> 'change Sheets to suit
> Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
> Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")
>
> With ws1
>     'assumung that data stored in column C:E, Sheet1
>     lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
>     'can not make range from row 3 ???
>     Set rng = .Range("C1:E" & lastrow)
>     'clear all filters
>     .AutoFilterMode = False
>     With rng
>         'apply filter with criteria in column 3 of range C:E
>         'can not make filter in row 2 ???
>         .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
>         On Error Resume Next
>         'get only visible rows
>         Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
>         On Error GoTo 0
>     End With
>     'copy range
>     If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Range("A:C").Copy
>     'paste from row 3
>     ws2.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
>     'delete no needed row
>     ws2.Rows(3).Delete
>     'clear all filters
>     .AutoFilterMode = False
>     End With
> Application.CutCopyMode = False
>   If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
>     ws1.Range("2:2").AutoFilter
>     End If
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Re: 1 - Is it because it's assuming Row 2 is the header row of your filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this quick fix, assuming your headers on both sheets are in the first row:

```
Sub COPY_SA()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
'change Sheets to suit
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")

With ws1
    'assumung that your data stored in column A:D, Sheet1
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:D" & lastrow)
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        'apply filter
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0"
        On Error Resume Next
        'get only visible rows
        Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'copy range
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Range("A:A,C:D").Copy
    ws2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    'clear all filters
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

To answer your questions:

> 1. Why this function always copy row A2? Even if value is "0".

That's because you have set a range starting from the second row and applied a filter to it.

We can change that in the code through setting the range from `A1:D & Lastrow` and also paste it to `ws2.Range("A1")`.

> 2. How to copy just value, no formatting?

Yes it's possible, but you'll need to copy and paste as `xlValues` as explained by @Peh [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788641/9758194)

The change in code therefore is to `.Copy` a range and in the next line `.PasteSpecial` the `xlValues`.

> 3. Is it possible to skip column B when copy? "C" from Sheet1 will be "B" in Sheet2, etc.

Yes instead of copying the whole range, we can specify which columns you would want to copy, this can be a non-contiguous range of columns.

We can change the `.Copy` part to include only these specific columns we need.

---

I'm sure the whole thing can be written neater but this should at least do what you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick help. Now I'm confused with copy range: ("A:A,C:D"). During copy in Sheet1 I want to ignore rows 1 and 2. Sheet2 range is no issue: ws2.Range("A3"). Rest is perfect :)

Comment: I'm sorry but missed issue with A column. Script do not copy value. From for example:  
  
" =HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("Link.jpg"") "
   
makes
   
" #VALUE! "
   
Detailed function from column A in my second post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57625534/excel-vba-automatic-function-reset-image-load