# Excel VBA automatic function reset / image load

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using function OnMouseOver to load specific picture based on text in cell.

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

My issue is that I have to use "reset" function to remove loaded picture. So I have to move mouse to next cell, with function to remove picture.
Is it possible to modify function that picture is present only when mouse is over cell?

Comment: I am not sure if you understand how your code works. "Is it possible to modify function that picture is present only when mouse is over cell?" - your code has nothing to do with mouse except of function's name.

Comment: Im useing it with hyperlink function and it works as onmouseover :) =HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("Link.jpg"")

Comment: Yes, it works like you described it. Incredible, once again "I know that I know nothing" in Excel. Sorry. Without Worksheet Events (run reset on Selection Change- but you must click any cell outside to run Reset macro) my first idea is to make reset function with hyperlink around your cell with picture eg. you have =HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("Link.jpg"") in B2 and =HYPERLINK(reset()) in A1:C1, A3:C3 and A2 and C2.

Comment: This is working solution. Agree. Still searching for something alternative. To be in A column. I could use delay function and reset, but sometimes you might need to keep picture for longer time :/