# How to select all rows at the bottom of a table that match today's date

Tags: vba, find, copy, rows

I would like to have a VBA macro in Excel that copies all entire rows where the value in the 10th column matches today's date and pastes that to another worksheet. Given that the table is chronically ranked, the most recent dates are at the bottom of the table and therefore the Find action should start at the last row of the table to be more efficient.

I have the following code in VBA so far:

```
Sub Test()

Dim TodaysDate As Date
Dim LastRows As Long

TodaysDate = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B28")

LastRows = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(10).Find(What:=TodaysDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

Rows(LastRows).Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: A more rigid idea would maybe be to filter your entire table on todays date, and [copy all visible lines instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788335/only-copy-visible-range-in-vba)

Answer (score 0):

As commented, instead of trying to find the top and bottom of a range somewhere on your sheet, it could be better to `.AutoFilter` your data on your criteria instead. Meaning you will only have the needed data displaying. You can then use `.SpecialCells(XlCellTypeVisible)` to copy all the cells currently on screen, and copy them to a different sheet. This is example code, not tailored to your needs, but should display the concept:

```
Sub filtercophee()

With Sheet1.Range("A1:J12")
    .AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="=" & DateValue(Now), Operator:=xlAnd
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheet2.Range("a1")
End With

Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```